# How can I decode Lycoming engine number?

Tags: piston-engine, lycoming

How can I decode Lycoming engine number suffices?
What does D3G mean in o-320-D3G or D2A in o-320-D2A?
Is there any chart or tabel for decode suffixes?

Answer (score 5):

I got the following information for this [website](https://www.lycoming.com/sites/default/files/SSP-110-1%20Certificated%20Engines.pdf):

[image]

Also if you scroll down here you can see the model numbers that you talk about in your question.

[image]

The last character seems to be an indication of the variant of the engine as shown in the document.  The D indicates Dual Magnetos and the 2 or 3 seems to indicate some type of counterweight application.

Answer (score 0):

This [PDF](https://www.lycoming.com/sites/default/files/SSP-110-1%20Certificated%20Engines.pdf) on Lycoming's web site covers it. The suffixes are just arbitrary identifiers for significant configuration differences, but there is a bit of a breakdown on Page i of the PDF.  Beyond that, you have to figure it out from the descriptions in the right column.  If you study them the logic should start to emerge.

Comment: He didn't say about suffixes that's my problem

Comment: You should copy out and cite relevant portions of the linked page, links die, pages change, sites get shut down, etc. "Link only" answers are very much discouraged.

Comment: He needs to see the entire document, not just a sample.  I changed the link to the root document on Lycoming's site.  That link shouldn't be going anywhere.

Comment: @JohnK that link went somewhere :)